# Get a complete view of a long DNA sequence of a Biostrings object in R

Tags: r, bioconductor, dna-sequence

I'm tried to get reverse complement of a DNA sequence in R applying Biostrings package.
The length of sequence is around 900 and I want to see it completely but R shows an abstract version with some dots between the codes.
Is there anyway to get it completely?

```
> library("Biostrings")
> d <- DNAString("CTGTTGAAGCGTCAGATGGATAAGCATCCATAATTTACTGTCCATATCCAAGACCTCATAGTATTCCTCGGGCATGAATTTAATTGGCGGGGTCGGGGTTCAAGTAAGCCGTATTTTGGCTTCGCCGCCGCGAATTTGAATGCGAGGCGTCTCCTCAAAGATGAGTAACGGCGTCCTGGGCTTCACAGAACTTTCGTGAGAAAACTCTAAGACTCTACAGAGATCACAAATGGTTTCAGCCCAGACTCTATTACTTGGGAGTAAGGGGGTTGACAACTCGCCACTCTATTTCCCATCATCTGCCCGCAGCTGCGACTGGGCCGAACCGAGATGGATATAGGAATAAAATGTGGTGGTGTTGCCGTGCTCTTTTCGTCCGCGTGTCCATGGCGAGGACAGCTATTTTCCTCTAAAGCCCATGTAGATCGCCTCGATCCCTCGTAAGACCCGGCTGCAGTCTGACGCCCCGACAAATAAGCTACCGCCTCCTAAACCATCCCCGATTCAGATGCGTGCTAACTTCGTGTTTCGGCCTAGCTTTAAGGGTACCGTCAGTCACCGCGACTCATAGCTGTACTCCTTCAGAATAAGGTAGTCCCGATCGTACACGTAGCTACAGAGGTATCAGACACGAGCTCGCGTCAATTCGACTCTTCGAGGCTGTGTGCCCCAGCTCCTCAGGGATCGCAATTTAGCAATCAAGAGATCTTGCCTCGTATCAATGATTTTCGCAGTTGGGTTCACGCCCCCTACAATAGCGCACCGCCTGTGTGCAAAGAAATTTTCTGGTACGTAAGATTCGAGGGAGTAGGGACGAAACATTCATGGCGATAGCAGATTTCCGAGGGCTACGGTGTAGCGGATACTAACCTCCGCGTGGTATAGATAGATACTTACCAAGGACACATGCTCTTCCTGTATAGCCGTTCCCG")
> rc <- reverseComplement(d)
> rc
  932-letter "DNAString" instance
seq: CGGGAACGGCTATACAGGAAGAGCAT...TGCTTATCCATCTGACGCTTCAACAG
```

Comment: What does give `print(rc)` ? (Didn't found the package you're using to test)

Comment: print(rc) worked exactly as above (rc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `as.character`:

```
> d = DNAString(paste0(sample(c("A","C","T","G"),600,TRUE),collapse=""))
> d
  600-letter "DNAString" instance
seq: CACATTTCTGAAGGTGTTGAGCGGCATCATATAAAC...CATAAACATAATTGCTTGTTTAGTCTACCAAACGCT
> as.character(d)
[1] "CACATTTCTGAAGGTGTTGAGCGGCATCATATAAACGCTCCCCCTTCAACTGTATAGTCCGGCACAGTAGGCTTAGGATATCACCGATGTGTCCGCCACGAAGCTCGAAGACCCGCCTCAAACAGGGCGCACGACCCGCTATATCCAACAATGAGTTCGACCCTGGATCCGTGCATTACATAGGCGACATGTGTGAAAAACTTTGCGTATCTCGGGCTTGCGCCTTTACTCCATGACTTTCTTTCGAACCTTAAATGACTGGTGCATACCCCTGCTTGTCCGTAAGGGAACGGACGGTTGGTATATCTTGAGCACGAGTAAGGGCGCTGATACCCCTTTGCTCGTCATTGATGGGCCAATGTGATGTTGACGTTGCTTGAAGGATTGTACTGGGGTTAATTTTTACGGGCGGAATTGGCTTCACAGTAATACGGACTGTGTAACAAGCGAGCCCCTTAAACGTGCAGACACTAAATAGCGGGCGAGTTACCTTTCATCAGGCACAGGTTAACTTTGGAAAAGGTCCACTTGAACCTCATTTGAAACCAAAGACCGTTATATATGCATAAACATAATTGCTTGTTTAGTCTACCAAACGCT"
```

Note you don't want to be doing this too much since `BioStrings` tries hard to be efficient at handling long strings. If you are trying to write this to a file there are other ways of doing it...

Answer (score 3):

You can use `toString` or `as.character`.

See the [documentation on coercion of XStrings](http://web.mit.edu/~r/current/arch/i386_linux26/lib/R/library/Biostrings/html/XString-class.html):

> ### Description
>
> The DNAString, RNAString and AAString classes are similar containers but with the more biology-oriented purpose of
>   storing a DNA sequence (DNAString), an RNA sequence (RNAString), or a
>   sequence of amino acids (AAString).
>
> All those containers derive directly (and with no additional slots)
>   from the XString virtual class.
>
> #### Coercion
>
> In the code snippets below, x is an XString object.
>
> `as.character(x)`: Converts x to a character string.
>
> `toString(x)`: Equivalent to as.character(x).

If you do `class(rc)` you will see that it is a `DNAString` so this documentation applies.

Comment: Thank you Antoine for your nice explanation!